# How Do I combined two datasets So that the Date combine into one column and all other columns remain?

Tags: merge, sas

I am trying to merge two data sets.

```
 Table A

 Date       |      x      |      y
 01.02.12   |      98     |     102
 03.06.18   |      6      |     44
 06.23.14   |      59     |     14


 Table B

 Date      |       w      |    z
01.02.12   |       94     |    94 
07.25.15   |       55     |    65
06.23.14   |       44     |    55
```

I want to merge the two table so that x, y, w,z  are all separate columns and the dates combine so that every date in both tables is listed in the new table.

```
Desired Table

  Date       |      x     |  y     |  w     |   z 
 01.02.12    |     98     |  102   |   94   |   94
 03.06.18    |      6     |   44   |   .    |   .
 07.25.15    |      .     |    .   |   55   |   65
 06.23.14    |     59     |  14    |   44   |   55
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your two files are sorted by DATE then just MERGE them.

```
data want;
   merge A B ;
   by date;
run;
```

PS Don't use two digit years. Remember Y2K.

Answer (score 1):

Write a Proc Sql.

```
proc sql;
    create table DesiredTable as
           select *
           From TableA a
           Full join TableB b on a.Date = b.Date;    
quit;
```

Comment: Somehow the select seems off.

Comment: I see what you mean, Give me a few mins and ill fix it to better fit.

Comment: Take a look at it now.

Comment: @nyfaria you may want to look at the coalesce function. Very handy in these cases.